# Am I going to clog my memory by running this loop long-term?

Tags: python, memory-management

Thanks for your time and for looking at this question!

I am creating a Python script to run on a Raspberry Pi Zero.  The idea is that it will scroll a very long text (the Lord of the Rings trilogy) one line at a time in an endless loop on an attached screen.

I have gotten the loop working with the following code and a sample text.  I am not, however, very familiar with the way Python uses memory.  Will this method continue to take increasing amounts of memory as each line is generated and printed (or, to put it another way, is this eventually going to freeze up)?

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

book = open('ave.txt', 'r')
lines = book.readlines()

position = 0

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = tk.Text(self, height=6, width=40)
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        self.readbook()

    def readbook(self):
        global position
        self.text.insert("end", lines[position])
        self.text.see("end")
        position += 1
        self.after(1000, self.checkloop)

    def checkloop(self):
        global position
        if position == 6:
            position = 0
            self.text.insert("end", '\n' + '\n')
            self.readbook()
        else:
            self.readbook()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root =tk.Tk()
    frame = Example(root)
    frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

(Thanks to Bryan Oakley, who provided the framework for this implementation with his answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671211/15277790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of complexity here that isn't addressed. Assuming you have 512mb I don't think so. What is the size of your aggregate document? The documentation for readlines() states that it loads the entire document into memory (which is already opened in memory thus a copy), parses each line as a string, and stores those in an array. If the entire document is like 25mb you should be good. You could always iterate through the lines using something like

```
with open('lor.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        pass
```

so that you don't reload the entire document into memory at once.

Comment: I don't have the aggregate document fully prepared yet, but by my best estimate it will only be about 3mb.  What originally worried me wasn't as much loading the document into memory, but the continuously generated output.  I wasn't sure if each output line occupies memory, since it remains in the GUI.

Comment: I am guessing it has to store a local version of that text widget as tkinter is intended to be a full-fledged (albeit stripped down) desktop gui app. It will keep a local version in case you decide to dynamically add events or something to it, it won't just naively write it to whatever gui buffer is on the peripheral you have it hooked up to. At least if you read it in line by line you will know that you will only have a couple versions of the document in memory for a brief second before your file and line instances are gc'd, as opposed to reading the whole thing in a third time.