# auto scroll text box in python for a beginner

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, autoscroll

I have a text box that auto populates with information that later I can export to a csv file.
# Add a scroll bar for the text box

```
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, command=output_text.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
output_text['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
```

How do I set the scrollbar to auto scroll down as the data populates the text box.  currently, I am manually scrolling down to see results as they come in.

I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: You can call `output_text.see('end')` after the call to `insert()` when adding text. Then your text box should snap to the bottom as text is inserted. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30671211/8512262)